# Wrong data receiving in my Arduino by bluetooth

Tags: arduino-uno, bluetooth, android, hc-06

I have programmed a client-server between an Arduino and my mobile app in Android. I´m using a buetooth HC-06. For the moment is a very basic code just to turn ON/OFF a led, regulate its voltage, and receive the charge of the battery.

This is my Arduino code for receiving the message:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <TimerOne.h>
SoftwareSerial hc06(2,3);

char command;
String string;
boolean ledon = false;
const byte MAX_STRING_LEN = 40; 
const int  BLINK_INTERVAL = 1000;

char inputString[MAX_STRING_LEN];  // a string to hold incoming data

int BatteryPin = A0;    // select the input pin for the potentiometer
int sensorValue = 0;  // variable to store the value coming from the sensor
float BatteryCar = 0;
int PercentageBatt = 0;
int intensidad = 0;
byte strLen   = 0;                 // current length of rec'd string

#define led 11
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  hc06.begin(9600);
  pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
  Timer1.initialize(10000); // set a timer of length 10000 microseconds (or 0.01 sec - or 1Hz => the led will blink 5 times, 5 cycles of on-and-off, per second)
  Timer1.attachInterrupt( SendVoltage );
}
void loop()
{

  sensorValue = analogRead(BatteryPin);
  BatteryCar = sensorValue * (5.0 / 1023.0);
  if (hc06.available() == 0)
  {
    analogWrite(led, 0);
    delay (10);
  }
  while(hc06.available() > 0)
  {
    command = ((byte)hc06.read());
    if((command == '\n') || (command == '\r'))
    {
      command =='\0';
      break;
    }
    else if (command == 'O')
      analogWrite(led, 255);
    else
      analogWrite(led, 0);
    delay(10);   
    Serial.println(command);
  } 
}

void SendVoltage ()
{

  PercentageBatt = (BatteryCar * 100)/4;
  hc06.println(PercentageBatt);
}
```

This is the data that I´m receiving:

[image]

It supposed that i should only receive "O" or "F". Any suggestion??

thanks in advanced,

Comment: It would appear that whatever is sending the data is sending something else.  Since we cannot see any of that code nobody can do anything but guess at why.

Comment: simply ignore unexpected data

Comment: why are you printing the value of *command* after you modify its value?

Comment: note:  substituting \0 for \r and for \n is kind of pointless

Comment: Does your HC-06 actually run at 9600 baud? Is your serial monitor set for 9600 baud?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after a lot of research, it seems that my main problem was that I´m receiving and sending information at the same time. And with the library Softwareserial, only 1 can be active at the same time.
I found two solutions, but to be honest I'm not complete satisfy with neither of them. However, for my application will work.

The first solution: Is to used the HardwareSerial (pin 0,1) itself, instead of using the pin 2 and 3. When I used those, it didn't have any problem. Although I decided no to used because it help me debugging my code.

The second solution: Is to decrease the frecuency of what I´m sending. For me its ok I send the data every second. So my code would be like this:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <TimerOne.h>
SoftwareSerial hc06(2,3);

char command;
String string;
boolean ledon = false;
const byte MAX_STRING_LEN = 40; 
const int  BLINK_INTERVAL = 1000;

char inputString[MAX_STRING_LEN];  // a string to hold incoming data

int BatteryPin = A0;    // select the input pin for the potentiometer
int sensorValue = 0;  // variable to store the value coming from the sensor
float BatteryCar = 0;
int PercentageBatt = 0;
int intensidad = 0;
byte strLen   = 0;                 // current length of rec'd string

#define led 11
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  hc06.begin(9600);
  pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
  Timer1.initialize(1000000);
  Timer1.attachInterrupt( SendVoltage );
}
void loop()
{

  sensorValue = analogRead(BatteryPin);
  BatteryCar = sensorValue * (5.0 / 1023.0);
  if (hc06.available() == 0)
  {
    analogWrite(led, 0);
    delay (10);
  }
  while(hc06.available() > 0)
  {
    command = ((byte)hc06.read());
    if((command == '\n') || (command == '\r'))
    {
      command =='\0';
      break;
    }
    else if (command == 'O')
      analogWrite(led, 255);
    else
      analogWrite(led, 0);
    delay(10);   
    Serial.println(command);
  } 
}

void SendVoltage ()
{

  PercentageBatt = (BatteryCar * 100)/4;
  hc06.println(PercentageBatt);
}
```

I have read about [this](https://www.pjrc.com/teensy/td_libs_AltSoftSerial.html) library (AltSoftSerial), but I couldn't get it work. I have usde the pin 8 and 9, but nothing.